# Flutter: "Being able to run the application while the phone screen is locked

Tags: flutter, locking, screen

I am developing a counter application controlled by voice buttons.
What do I need to do to allow the application to continue running while the phone screen is locked?

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _startVolumeWatcher();
  }

  void _startVolumeWatcher() {
    VolumeWatcher.addListener((vol) {
      setState(() {
        if (vol > _previousVolume) {
      _counter++;
          Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
            VolumeWatcher.setVolume(0.0);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```